# Passwords in Emacs tramp mode editing

Tags: emacs, ssh, passwords, tramp

I'm using emacs [tramp mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) to remotely edit files over ssh. The problem is that every time I save the file I'm editing I have to enter my user password. I find that very annoying. How can I write my password only once / editing session?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah, from the [tramp docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Password-caching.html) on password caching you can set:

```
(setq password-cache-expiry nil)
```

which requires the package [password-cache.el](http://braeburn.aquamacs.org/code/master/lisp/password-cache.el).

Also, in the tramp sources, it mentions reading the [ssh-agent(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent) man page, which shows how to set it up so that you don't have to re-enter passwords (inside, or outside of Emacs):

> There are two main ways to get an
>   agent set up: The first is that the
>   agent starts a new subcommand into
>   which some environment variables are
>   exported, eg ssh-agent xterm &.  The
>   second is that the agent prints the
>   needed shell commands (either sh(1) or
>   csh(1) syntax can be generated) which
>   can be evalled in the calling shell,
>   eg eval `ssh-agent -s` for Bourne-type
>   shells such as sh(1) or ksh(1) and
>   eval `ssh-agent -c` for csh(1) and
>   derivatives.

Comment: The package name is `package-cache`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(setq password-cache-expiry nil)
```

Comment: Should this go into my .emacs file?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Trey Jackson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840279/passwords-in-emacs-tramp-mode-editing/840431#840431), there are a few more ways you can choose:

- If you're on a *nix system, you can mount the remote directory with [FUSE/SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), and therefore you can edit files as they were on the local file system.
- Use [SSH public key authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/).

Answer (score 1):

Using public key (RSA) authentication is more secure and much more convenient.  On a GNU/Linux system (and maybe others, I don't know) you typically would unlock your private key once per login session with a password and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

use SSH public key authentication.